# how to understand the static variable defined inside of a function block in c++?

Tags: c++

I was reading the following code and would like to know whether my understanding is correct or not.

```
// Passw1.cpp
// The functions getPassword() and timediff() to read and examine a password.

#include <iostream>                
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

long timediff(void);
static string secret = "ISUS";
static long maxcount = 3, maxtime = 60;




int main()                                 // Enters and checks a password 
{

   bool ok_flag = false;                           // Return value: true, if password is ok.
   string word;

   int count = 0, time = 0;
   timediff();                                     // To start the stop watch
   while(ok_flag != true && ++count <= maxcount)
   {
      cout << "\n\nInput the password: ";
      cin.sync();                                     // Clear input buffer
      cin >> setw(20) >> word;
      time += timediff();
      if( time >= maxtime )                           // Within time limit?
         break;

      if( word != secret)
         cout << "Invalid password!" << endl;
      else
         ok_flag = true;
    }
    //return ok_flag;                                    // Result
    return 0;
}





long timediff()
// Returns the number of seconds after the last call.
    {
     static long sec = 0;
     long oldsec = sec;      // Saves previous time.
     time( &sec);            // Reads new time.
     return (sec - oldsec);  // Returns the difference.
    }
```

So, the variable sec is defined as static long inside of the function timediff. It means, when the coding flow leaves the function timediff, the variable sec is not destroyed. Then, later when the second or third time the control flow reaches the function timediff, the variable sec still holds the number of seconds after the last call, right?

Comment: Sounds correct to me.

Comment: That's it - and - Don't do stuff like that if you work in any professional capacity. Why? Try to write a test for a function like that... You are unable to set the preconditions for your tests. And dont even try to think about what happens if multiple threads call a function like that....